# Reading Excel file from URL

Tags: java, excel, url

How to read the Excel file which is present in some URL?  Excel file is not present in my local system and it is not in my Google docs.

Comment: *"How to read the Excel file which is present in some URL?"*  How do you read it now?

Comment: I'm reading it using Apache-POI by specifying the local path

Comment: Gee, can you vague that up for me?  Link to the JavaDocs for the method.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Apache-POI](http://poi.apache.org/) Java API for reading Excel File.

Comment: and how to use apache poi to load data from an url ?